# Robotium Solo 4.0 pauses after typing text

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

I'm using Robotium Solo 4.0 to write some functional tests for an Android app.  The following sequence is giving me issues.  I'm running on a Nexus 4.

```
View cartIcon = solo.getView(R.id.cartBtn);
solo.clickOnView(cartIcon);

//Animation happens in app here for about 5 seconds before the email/password boxes are visible

solo.typeText((EditText)solo.getView(R.id.emailEdit), LOGIN_EMAIL);
solo.typeText((EditText)solo.getView(R.id.passwordEdit), LOGIN_PASSWORD);


//Execution pauses here for 30 seconds or so, then picks up at normal speed where it left off.
solo.clickOnView((Button)solo.getView(R.id.loginBtn), true);
```

As you can see in the comment above, after filling in the login email and password on the login screen, the test execution pauses for a long while, until finally the login button is clicked and execution continues as normal.  Does anyone have a solution for this?

**UPDATE**

One thing to note is that after clicking on the cartIcon, there is an animation that takes about 5 seconds to complete on the next activity before the emailEdit and passwordEdit EditText views are available.  I'm wondering if Robotium is trying to type into these fields too soon and fails, then waits for a timeout before moving on.

I tried to do a solo.waitForText("Login") before typing the email and password, but that did not help.  Any other ideas?

**SOLUTION**

Oops - I'm an idiot.  R.id.emailEdit and R.id.passwordEdit were the wrong elements and were not present on this page.  I debugged and noticed both were null, which apparently causes Robotium to wait for a timeout before it proceeds.  After I swapped in the proper element IDs, everything works as expected.

It would be nice if Robotium threw an exception when trying to interact with a null view.

Comment: I have not seen this issue before, does it happen pre solo 4.0?

Comment: I have not tried an older version as this is my first time using Robotium.  I could try downloading an older version and see if it happens.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of time out happening with the previous typeText calls.  Perhaps Robotium is trying to input the text before the page is loaded fully.  I'll update the question with more details.

Comment: I woukd suggest adding in a waitforview method before you try to set the text. I will dig out some code later. On the train right now!

Comment: Hey Paul - see my latest update - turns out I was using the wrong id's for my UI elements and both views were coming back as null...but apparently Robotium does not throw exceptions in this case.  Sorry for wasting your time.